# Invalid Floating point operation Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, pascalscript, fastreport

I'm coding a program with Pascal in fastreport, The problem appear when I try to show the result of a division. this is my program:

```
var
relec_tp_for_pa, tp_for_pa, relec_tt_tp, total_tp, coef_relec : Real = 0;
relec_vt : Integer = 0;

procedure MasterData1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);               
begin

if ( ( <EJobsQuery."SERV_ID"> = 54 ) )  then        
   begin
       relec_tp_for_pa := tp_for_pa;                                      
       relec_vt := relec_vt + <EJobsQuery."EJOB_VOLUME">;                                      
       relec_tt_tp := relec_tt_tp + tp;
       total_tp := total_tp + tp;
   end;

coef_relec := StrToFloat(FormatFloat('0.0000', relec_tt_tp / total_tp));

relec_pa.Text := FormatFloat('0.00', relec_vt /(relec_tp_for_pa * coef_relec));                
relec_pr.Text := FloatToStr( relec_vt / relec_tt_tp );                 

end;
```

Both of this divisions:
-relec_vt /(relec_tp_for_pa * coef_relec)
-relec_vt / relec_tt_tp
 
are giving me the error : Invalid Floating point operation

I'm coding in the FastReport 4.11.4 a report.
under 32 bits OS if this can help.

Thanks again.

Comment: Your variables are uninitialised. What do you expect? Don't do that.

Comment: @gnasher729 In my program all variables are initialised so this is not the problem, thanks

Comment: Ok @RyanVincent I will try this solution

Comment: This is not your program. Please show the real code. How can we see where the problem is if you post some fake code?

Answer (score 4):

From what you've coded it seems that You divide by zero!

> -relec_vt /(relec_tp_for_pa * coef_relec)
>
> -relec_vt / relec_tt_tp

Since

```
relec_tp_for_pa := tp_for_pa
```

is definetly ZERO!

```
relec_tp_for_pa * coef_relec
```

**Will also be zero!**

For relec_tt_tp I just can try to guess, since this code **is not a complete example.**

```
total_tp := total_tp + tp
```

total_tp is zero, and if tp is also zero You'd end up in a division by zero.

Generally I'd always check if your divisor is not zero!

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for your reply. I don't think that's the problem because I checked the content of those variables by displaying them separately.

Comment: Well this is the code you've posted. And in this code relec_tp_for_pa is defenetly zero!